# Hide title section of shiny dashboard in a way that the toggle button is in the most left spot of the dashboard header

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to know how can I totally skip the title section from shinydashboard header. So the first object to see will be the toggle button that hides and display the sidebar. Now if I set `titlewidth` to 0 there is still a small gap between the toggle button and the beginning of the page. Something like:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
  titleWidth = 0
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding this bit of CSS help?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
 
  dashboardHeader(
    titleWidth = 0
  
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type="text/css",".sidebar-toggle{ position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}")
  
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: sure it does but when I hide the sidebar using the toggle the gap re-appears

Comment: also could you use this css logic here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74574772/add-a-company-logo-right-after-shiny-dashboard-header-toggle-button

Comment: the gap doesn't re-appear when I toggle the sidebar on my Chrome browser.