# Add a company logo right after shiny dashboard header toggle button

Tags: r, shinydashboard

How can I add a company logo right after the toggle button that is in shiny dashboard header like:
[image]

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    titleWidth = 0,
    title = div("", id = "home_logo", a(href = "#Home",
                                        (img(src = "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com", height = "25px", 
                                             style = "position: relative; top:-5px; left: -40px;")) ))

  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE
    
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(

    
    tags$style(type="text/css",".sidebar-toggle{ position: absolute;
    left: 23rem;
}
.skin-white .main-header .logo {
    background-color: #3c8dbc;}"),
    
    
  )
  )                                

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this with CSS?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = div("", id = "home_logo", a(href = "#Home",
                                        (img(src = "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com", height = "25px", 
                                             style = "position: relative; top:-5px; left: -5rem;")) ))
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE
    
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    
    tags$style(type="text/css",".sidebar-toggle{ position: absolute;
    left: -23rem;
}
.skin-white .main-header .logo, .skin-blue .main-header .logo, .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover{
    background-color: #3c8dbc;}"),


  )
)                                

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it works on your example but not on my edit. check it out plz

Comment: I cannot get your edited reprex to reproduce without errors. My above answer outputs the desired look from your question. What other functionality/ style are you trying to add?

Comment: sorry plz check now

Comment: still getting errors?

Comment: i gave you the answer but still getting issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593221/adding-am-image-in-shinydashboard-header-hides-the-toggle-button